# Why is the graph of this vector equation a semi circle?

Tags: vectors

I have: $\mathbf{r}(t) = (t^2 - 1)\mathbf{j} + 2t\mathbf{k}$, $-1\leq t \leq 1$ and $\mathbf{r}(t) = (2\cos t)\mathbf{i} + 2(\sin t)\mathbf{k}$, $0 \leq t \leq \pi$.

I've already graphed them but I don't understand why they are semi circles on the graph. Why aren't they just straight line vectors connecting the two points?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The graph of $\mathbf{r}(t) = (t^2 - 1)\mathbf{j} + 2t\mathbf{k}$,   $-1\leq t \leq 1$ is not a semicircle, it's a segment of a parabola.

Comment: Ah, I see. How did you know that it was a parabola?

Comment: Cause $y=t^2-1$ and $z=2t$ implies $y=\frac{z^2}{4}-1$, so $y$ coordinate can be regarded as a quadratic function of $z$ coordinate, and it's known that quadratic functions have parabolas as graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one has the property that its $x$ component squared plus its $y$ component squared is constant,
$$x^2+y^2=4\cos^2t+4\sin^2t=2^2$$
 and thus is a circle (of radius $r=2$). What makes it a *semi*circle is the fact that $t$ ranges only over $0\le t\le \pi$ rather than, say, $0\le t\le 2\pi$.

The first one is not a circle/semicircle since (as you can check), $$x^2+y^2=t^4+2t^2+1\not=\text{ constant}.$$

**Edit:** Some pictures to help see things... Here's the sequence of vectors as well as the paramteric curve they trace out for the first function

[image]

and here's the same type of picture for the second function

[image]